# How to access Gradle extra properties from Java (not android)?

Tags: java, gradle, build, properties

task in `build.gradle` file -

```
task automationTest(type: Test) {
    ext.env = rootProject.hasProperty('TS1') ? rootProject['TS2'] : 'TS1'
    println env //printing passed pararmeter auccessfully
}
```

now I want to pass env in Login class

```
driverThread.get(GetProperty(env));
```

where GetProperty function is

```
public String GetProperty(String Prop) throws IOException {
    FileReader reader=new FileReader("Prop.properties");
    Properties p=new Properties();
    p.load(reader);
    System.out.println("Property found" + p.getProperty(Prop));
    return p.getProperty(Prop);
}
```

Comment: Where does `GetProperty` reside?

Comment: GetProperty is in another java class

Comment: I know i can access env variable from build.gradle to any java class by using system property systemProperty 'env',System.properties['env'] ?: 'dev' command in build.gradle, from console gradle -Denv=test <taskname> and then accessing System.getProperty("env") from anywhere in src but i want to understand if i create env as ext property or project property then how can i use env from any java class?